# Non-mod Steward Badge: Keep Reviewing or Don't

Tags: discussion, badges

For those of you who don't know, I have been very active on the *Review Queues* lately, achieving *Top Reveiwer of the Day* almost every day by a wide margin. This means that I am currently 80 *First Posts* away from a *Steward* badge.

It occurs to me that I will likely be the first non-moderator to achieve this badge, and this sparked a question in my mind. It makes sense for someone like David to continue reviewing long past his *Steward* badges because he is a moderator. However, as a non-mod, perhaps I should step aside at 1000 and let other users reach 1000 themselves.

**Should I continue reviewing past 1000 reviews or should I step aside to let other users achieve what I might soon?**

Comment: Why limit yourself? If you feel that you can contribute to make this a better site, GO FOR IT!

Comment: Granted getting a gold badge was a good incentive there's no reason to stop. Tho not in the diamond sense you are a moderator as you have certain privileges the average user doesn't and as such should exercise them as such. This site is curated and run by us the community, not everyone will set such a goal and as long as you're helping to clear the queues and guide new users, that is always welcome and appreciated. Perhaps set a new steward goal in another queue, some users stick to specific tags or queues. I personally focus on flags (lots), troublesome users, low quality content and spam.

Comment: Note that badges are mainly there to encourage good community service.  IMO nothing should be done *just to get a badge*, doing something for the sole purpose of getting a badge is called farming and is forbidden.  Badges are there to show off devotion to the site and community, they're not "objectives".  The purpose of reviewing is to enrich the site, not to get a badge, so by all means, go on reviewing!

Comment: 1000 reviews,  19 800 more to do...

Comment: step aside to let other users achieve

Comment: As you may have noticed, I've done a bit of reviewing over the past few days, since I reached the 500 limit. Just so you know, I'm not trying to compete. :) I'm on long term sick leave, and have quite a lot of time on my hands.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley I have, but I would encourage you to continue. As long as your taking your time, go review everything, if you want ;-) p.s. Get better!

Comment: Thanks for both the encouragement and the well wishes. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off congratulations on doing so many reviews and so quickly! Steward badge in 7 months is quite something!

So long as you are doing good reviews, and not just hammering on the buttons to get the badge, then there is no reason at all that you should stop*.
If you want to keep reviewing, then keep reviewing!
(Top reviewers on SO have over 45K reviews in one queue!)

SE actually does has review limits (20 per queue per day), that is all SE does to rate limit users; there is not max cap.

There is no reason why you should sop at 1000 reviews. I do not think SE ever designed it so that users feel that they should stop. (That would be quite counter intuitive) this is a community run site, if the most active users stop running the site what will happen?

Fun fact, [moderators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) as part of the job description are not required to do reviews.
That by design, as part of the reputation system, is left to the general users so the mods only have to deal with the emergency situation stuff AKA "flags."

---

<sub>* Only reason to stop is so David ♦ could remain in first :)</sub>

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this great answer and letting you know that I will continue reviewing past 1,000 (just earned my __Steward__ Badge; Yay!). I'm not sure I'll ever pass 45k, as that would be nuts, especially considering the size of our site. Once again, thanks!